# What is the best way to make a while loop faster?

Tags: python, while-loop

i have an script that computes the Sum of 1/n. It can do it for 10.000.000.000 in 20 min. But I think it can be better.

```
while i <= n:
    b = 1/i
    h = h+b
    i = 1+i
```

I cant realy think of a better way than rewriting the code from scartch. Any advise is helpfull.

Comment: Use a for loop.

Comment: Usually the solution for a problem like this is to use some clever math so you don't need a loop at all.

Comment: If you're willing to settle for an approximate answer, use `h = math.log(n) + 0.577216`.  That magic number is [Euler's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_constant) γ.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the built-in `sum()` function.

```
h = sum(1/x for x in range(i, n+1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code works in ~8 seconds on my computer:

```
import numpy as np
import time

start = time.time()
h = 0
for k in range(1, 10000):
    i = np.arange((k-1)*1e6+1, k*1e6, 1)
    h = h + np.sum(1/i)
end = time.time()
print("Result: " + str(h) + " in " + str(end-start) + " s" )
```

Edit: There were some minor mistakes.
Edit 2: There were some other minor mistakes, but I think it is correct now.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sum a lot of numbers, `numpy` is faster than list comprehension. Here is some profiling results on my Macbook Pro (M1 Pro chip)

```
import timeit

# list comprehension
t1 = timeit.timeit(stmt="h=sum(1/n for n in range(1, 1000))")
print(f"List comprehension duration: {t1} s")

# numpy
t2 = timeit.timeit(setup="import numpy as np",
                   stmt="h = np.sum(1/np.arange(1, 1000))")
print(f"Numpy duration: {t2} s")
```

prints

```
List comprehension duration: 50.729283083 s
Numpy summation duration: 5.766907249999996 s
```

If you are able to write down the analytical expression, `sympy` is blazingly fast

```py
import sympy
n = sympy.symbols("n")
# note that (n, start, end) means n = start, start+1, ..., end
h = sympy.Sum(1/n, (n, 1, 999)).evalf()
print(f"{h = }")
```

takes < 2s on my laptop.